# Xcode 10 'xxx' has different definitions in different modules; definition in module 'xx' first difference is function body

Tags: xcode10

In Xcode 9 just an warming, update to Xcode 10 changed to error[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error means the `ControllerImports.h` declares a function called `'xxx'` that is already declared in `UIKit+BJL_M9Dev.h`.

You'll either have to change the name of `'xxx'`, or overload it (if the language you're using supports that).

That's pretty much the most help I can give with the small amount of info provided.